# Detaching SQLAlchemy instance so no refresh happens

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I want to detach an instance of a class from my session but it should still be available for reading (without emitting a query). I have been scanning through the documentation for days now, but every approach I try leads to the message

```
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <MyModel at 0x36bb190> is not bound to a Session;
attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

I am working with the `zope.sqlalchemy` transaction manager in Pyramid. I want my object to be usable **after** the transaction has been committed. I only need it to read the "cached" value, i.e. those that were in it before the transaction was commited.

The only possible solution I could find was to wrap the class (or the attributes itself) and then track the changes manually (I could do that but it is really ugly and not at all Pythonic).

Is there a way I can prevent SQLAlchemy from trying to refresh these values?

As a fallback I would even be open to just returning `None`, as long as the above error doesn't get thrown after the transaction as been committed

Comment: What kind of attribute are you trying to read ?

Comment: Its a `PickleType` that is made mutable by my own `MutableDict.as_mutable()` function. But it seems once a commit happens all data gets removed from the states so you would have to query, whatever data you want (might be wrong here though...)

Answer (score 14):

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

I think you're looking for `expire_on_commit = False`

I believe this allows you to detach the object and continue to use it. Trying to modify it and commit however will lead to the `DetachedInstanceError`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The link however needs to be updated to: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

Comment: Check the next answer @shaffooo you really don't want this behavior, if it doesn't expire on commit you might find yourself dealing with old states, i.e. the db state changes won't be reflected in the session next time you query it

Answer (score 13):

You can do exactly this (for example for caching) by doing:

```
session.expunge(obj)
```

As per sqlalchemy documentation:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html?highlight=expire#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge

This will give you object that is in detached state that you can safely use - you need to remember you will not be able to read properties that would emit another query thus being tied to session - like relationship, this will end up with `DetachedInstanceError`.

By default a commit will issue an expire_all() which means all objects will refresh their state on read, by expunging them you detach them from the session so there should be no subsequent queries after you commit your transaction.

I would advise against disabling this functionality globally as the other comments suggest as Mike Bayer generally suggest it is a good idea and a sane default for most people that can save you headaches in long run.

Just expunge things explictly when you need them.

Comment: This answer was more helpful for me.

Comment: I believe that sqlalchemy now expunges on `close()`.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(), expire_on_commit=False))
```

I had this problem too and using `expire_on_commit=False` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
@contextmanager
def make_session_scope(Session):
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    session.expire_on_commit = False
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

 with make_session_scope(session) as session:
      query = session.query(model)
```